# Is this number already known to be transcendental? Is there a survey about up-to-date trascendence results?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendence, transcendental-number-theory

Is the number $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n^2}}$ known to be transcendental?

Is there a survey with up-to-date transcendence results?

Comment: Would you please tell us what is your motivations?Thanks.

Comment: I'm writing a paper in which I show that a variation of the number above is an l^2-Betti number of something (cf. http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2030)

Comment: See also this answer of mine for a proof that this and other similar numbers are transcendental, and some related links. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41609/have-all-numbers-with-sufficiently-many-zeros-been-proven-transcendental/41760#41760

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake there. This series doesn't converge nearly fast enough for the results in the other question to apply.

Comment:  @George: I think you confuse the number from my question with $\sum \frac{1}{2^{2^n}}$.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have checked with [*Introduction to Algebraic Independence Theory*](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=liYae-vUZs4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=introduction+to+algebraic+independence+theory&source=bl&ots=6Kf4QYSDlS&sig=bJ2TfJ5Fi54ktqf56svrBYIkXyk&hl=en&ei=2BNZTfDtAcWSOq_PpPoE&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), where it is mentioned in the preface (p. V) that

> D. Bertrand and independently D. Duverney, Ke. Nishioka, Ku. Nishioka, I. Shiokawa (DNNS) deduced results on algebraic independence of the values of theta-functions at algebraic points and in particular derived the   transcendence of the sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n^2}$ for any algebraic $q$ satisfying $0 < |q| < 1$.

The precise references are not given but a little googling turned up the paper by D. Bertrand, [Theta Functions and Transcendence](https://rdcu.be/cQ61t), *The Ramanujan Journal*, Vol. 1 (1997), pp. 339-350, which seems to be relevant. The second reference is DNNS, [Transcendence of Jacobi's theta series](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.3792%2Fpjaa.72.202), *Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci.*, Vol. 72 (1996), pp. 202-203.

Answer (score 11):

There is a family of functions called theta-functions. One of them - I think the standard notation for it might be $\theta_3$ - is given by $\theta_3(z)=\sum z^{n^2}$, so (modulo any mistakes in the definition I've given) your number is $\theta_3(1/2)$. Now the theta-functions are very well-studied, and I suspect there is a lot of information out there about the transcendence of their values at rational arguments. So I've given you a keyword to aid your searches.