# Transcendence of some number

Tags: nt.number-theory

Everybody knows that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}}$ is transcendental. 
Is number $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2^{k^2}}}$ algebraic or not?

Comment: I asked my mother if she knows that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}}$ is transcendental. She didn't know. [You lied](http://i.imgur.com/6PlRXhI.gif).

Comment: may be she lied

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is, and even the three numbers $\sum_{k \geq 0}{2^{-k^2}}$, $\sum_{k \geq 1}{k^22^{-k^2}}$ and $\sum_{k \geq 1}{k^42^{-k^2}}$ are algebraically independent. This results from algebraic independence results for theta functions, see Waldschmidt's excellent survey https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/SurveyTrdceEllipt2006.pdf, Corollary 52, and the reference given there: Nesterenko & Philippon, Introduction to algebraic independence theory, Lecture Notes in Mathematics, vol. 1752, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2001, Chapter 3.

Comment: I don't know if it is courageous to answer a question like "Is *** algebraic or not" with "yes it is" - mathematically the answer is correct, plus it's a nice Beatles song.

Answer (score 4):

I can't classify this question as a duplicate, but 
[Is this number already known to be transcendental? Is there a survey about up-to-date trascendence results?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55397/is-this-number-already-known-to-be-transcendental-is-there-a-survey-about-up-to?rq=1)

asks the same thing.

Introduction to algebraic Independence Theory, 
this number is transcendental.